# tkinter ask user to input value on entry widget in each iteration

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, button

there is root or window update() which refreshes the the label value. I am searching for a method which will stop iteration > will ask again user to enter value > then get new entry value and will continue on.

i have button which calls `goToUrl_Se()` function with `driver` argument which is also return value of another function.

```
def get_value_enrty():
    goToUrl_Se(driver)
    entry_value_pg.focus()
    return entry_value_pg.get()

#creating button widget for submit(running) scrape function
btn_submit=Button(fr_submit_entry_url,text='Scrape',font='Segoe 12',command=get_value_enrty)
```

Inside `goToUrl_Se()` I have loop which iterates 1)through urls taken from csv file, 2) as much as given by entry widget. I need after second iterstion(nested) finishes it again asks user how many pages to scrape in second(third, ..) taken url.

```
def goToUrl_Se(driver):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls + 1):
        xUrl = fileCSV.iloc[i, 1]
        print(xUrl,i)
        var_url.set(xUrl)
        window.update()
        # going to url(amazn) via Selenium WebDriver
        driver.get(xUrl)
        #show pages num
        count_of_pages=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="s-pagination-strip"]/span[last()]')
        #!!ask user each time when it comes to this line
        how_many_pages_in_val=entry_value_pg.get()
        ###how_many_pages_in_val=input('How many pages from {} do you want to scrape?: '.format(count_of_pages.text))
        ###print('scrape data from all {} pages'.format(how_many_pages_in_val))
        i_pages_to_scrpe=int(how_many_pages_in_val)
        if i_pages_to_scrpe>1:
            for i in range(1,i_pages_to_scrpe+1):
                # continue on if there is more pages to load and scrape
                # call again parse data--! going to next page should be before loop occurs to next line in csv
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=33)
                parse_data()
                a=str(i+1)
                print(a)
                locator='//a[@aria-label="Go to page '+a+'"]'
                print('go to {}'.format(a))
                wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator))).click()
                lbl_pg00['text'] = 'Page  ' + str(i) + '  has been scraped'
                window.update()
        else:
            parse_data()
        counter += 1##!!counter should help for solution, but I do not get into how to relate it with get_value_enrty()

    driver.quit()
```

What I need sth like input() function every time python reads line with entry it asks user to enter input value

**Upd:**
I added after() method but without effect in second iteration it tooks value in entry widget without waiting and asking for value to be inputted again

```
entry_value_pg.focus()
window.after(10)
print('taken')
how_many_pages_in_val=entry_value_pg.get()
```

Comment: Try [`tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.simpledialog.askinteger).

Comment: it resolved my problem . Thanks. I was looking for something <FocusOut> variable binding...